# e-utils api: get chromosome position for each snp on a gene

Tags: snp, phylogenetics, api

So I have the following e-utils api-link:

> https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/elink.fcgi?dbfrom=gene&db=snp&id=5726&retmode=json

it returns all the SNP-ids for the gene with the id 5726 as an example. Additionally to the SNP-ids I also need the SNP position and the genomic distance. Also I would need the chromosome but I could query that from the gene as well rather than for each SNP. Do you know how I can add all these informations to the resulting json/xml?

The first one in the resulting list is the SNP with the id 1490381980. Further information about it can be found on dbSNP: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/?term=1490381980%5BUID%5D

I really want to avoid creating a request for each single SNP and would prefer to query everything at once. Due to the unavoidable performance-issues. The Tas2R38 doesn't have that many SNPs but there are other genes with way more.

Comment: Hi @cowboy_patrick could you plase state/clarify what you mean by "to query everything at once. Due to unavoidable performance issues.".

Comment: It would be great if I could get all the SNPs and their positions with a single api-call for a specified gene. Instead of creating a call for each SNP on the variation services or something similar

Answer (score 2):

If your dataset is limited to human SNPs, and you know the list of SNPs, I would advise taking a look at the dedicated [NCBI Variation Services](https://api.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/variation/v0/).  This would be one request for each SNP, but if you fire off 1-2 per second, I think you'll be ok.

For example, for rs1490381980, you could try something like:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/variation/v0/refsnp/1490381980' \
   | jq '.primary_snapshot_data.placements_with_allele[] | "\(.seq_id) \(.alleles[0].allele.spdi.position)"'
```

It would be better to query for the SNP and parse the JSON in python, but `jq` helps provide an idea of what is possible.

Alternatively, you could download the JSON or VCF data from the [NCBI dbSNP FTP site](https://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/latest_release/), and process out the information you need.